# Warrning from unittest on models.DateTimeField with auto_now=True

Tags: django

I got model in Django 4.2.1 that has an autofield updated each time anytching is changed in record. Implemented only by this one line:

```
last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True)
```

In PGAdmin I see correct created records. And in standard usage I got no warnings inside container terminal. But whent I run tests by command inside container "python manage.py test" I recieve warnings like:

> warnings.warn( /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:1595:
> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField SMSNotification.last_modification
> received a naive datetime (2024-02-02 13:46:49.356514) while time zone
> support is active./bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: newline unexpected
> (expecting ")")
>
> warnings.warn(
> /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:1595:
> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField SMSNotification.last_modification
> received a naive datetime (2024-02-02 13:46:49.356514) while time zone
> support is active.

Is this a common unittest problem or my implementation of model? If should be ignored, can I configure test framework to avoid printing the warning?

Comment: Could you post a specific unit test that shows this warning?

Comment: It's a warnings that's printed before start any of tests. Even if i create a simple TestCase-inherit class and leave only the test: check if homepage is returned by a code 200.